# OpenCV Python не работает запись фотографии с камеры

Tags: python, opencv

Программа для создания фотографий через камеру.
Код:

```
import cv2, time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite("camera1.png", frame)
cap.release()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Python 3.8, Windows 7, установлена библиотека opencv-python, камера работает, не записывает файл

Comment: попробуйте вывести кадр на экран, чтобы увидеть, получается ли получить изображение от камеры:
**cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()**

Comment: А `ret` для чего нужен?

Comment: Exord, спасибо.

Comment: MBo, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773186/what-does-ret-and-frame-mean-here

Comment: @huker667 Да я в курсе. Это намёк, что не стоит его игнорировать